# Для чего в CSS нужны величины in, cm, pt и тд., если они не работают?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Беда в том, что эти величины нифига не абсолютные, а привязаны к ПИКСЕЛЯМ, а не к dpi дисплея. Т.е. хоть на мониторе компьютера, хоть на смартфоне (где пиксели в 2 раза мельче) 1 дюйм будет ВСЕГДА равен 96 пикселей. И квадрат, с заданными размерами 1х1 см на дисплее смартфона будет фактически равен 0.5х0.5 см. Куда смотрят веб-стандарты?...

Ситуация такова. Верстаю под PDA, и возникла эта проблема. Т.е. нельзя сделать шрифт (и другие объекты), нормального размера, воспринимаемым на всех устройствах, потому что везде разные ДПИ, а размер дюйма привязан к пикселям, и везде получается разный физический размер. Может быть я что-то неправильно верстаю? Исходники прилагаются.

[Страничка с квадратами 1мм, 1см и 3см](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24415302/dev/pda.html)

QR-код этой страницы:

[image: qr-код]

Answer (score 3):

Эти величины оставлены для совместимости. на заре, когда разрешение было очень близко, их можно было смело использовать.
Сейчас используйте em, %, реже px. Все. остальным - не рекомендую.
По поводу размеров: равного размера добиваться на разных устройствах можно именно-таки %.
Согласитесь, странно на экране, генеримом проектором на стене пытаться создать квадратик 1х1 см?

Comment: Пример с проектором - правильный.

Comment: Тю, а я думал это и сейчас актуально (хотя нигде не видел инфы про их устаревание). Всегда указывал в пикселях, т.к. мониторы примерно у всех одинаковые, и верстал только для них. А сейчас вдруг понадобилось для ПДА.

Насчет экрана проектора таки верно, но все же, если страница разрабатывается для устройств, с которых человек читает на расстоянии не более вытянутой руки, тут бы и см/мм пригодились.

И, да, никогда не понимал, относительно чего отсчитываются проценты? Может вы мне объясните? =)

Comment: Сорри а зачем использовать em и чем это лучше пикселей?

Comment: @kanaris, а вы какую-нибудь теорию по еденицам измерений в CSS читали?

Comment: @Artemis, em - это привязка к размеру шрифта. Лучше пикселей тем, что даже если по каким-то прричинам у вас браузер поменял этот размер, верстка не расползется, а растянет все элементы под размер букв. особенно это актуально именно для смартов, где браузеры творят с текстом что хотят.

1em = высота коробки под букву в данном шрифте. В общем случае em в пикселях численно равен размеру шрифта.

Comment: @kanaris, проценты отсчитываются относительно родительского элемента. 
Если width=33% - это будет чуть меньше трети ширины родительского элемента, с учетом padding.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, дружище, я с этим работаю уже черти сколько лет ;) я этих теорий достаточно начитался.